# android volley library - show cached result while retrieving

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using Volley and GSON for networking in my app. I have a news feen in the app. I want to show the previously downloaded and cached result right away while downloading the latest content. I have tried accessing the cache using `queue.getCache().get(url)` but this is always null.
How to properly show cached result while new content is being downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is always null, that means there is no chache for that url. Make sure you did not turned off caching with setShouldCache. Or in http header of response is cache-control: no-cache or max-age=0